# Paytabs recurring payment request with token is giving [422 - Unable to process your request] error

Tags: python, payment-gateway, tokenize, paytabs

I created a token by Paytabs Tokenization method, then latter on used the generated token to request again using `tran_class: recurring` but I'm getting `{'code': 422, 'message': 'Unable to process your request', 'trace': 'PMNT0102.65DCFAF6.0002C7A0'}` as response

**First time payment request payload**

```
payload = {
    "profile_id": PROFILE_ID,
    "tran_type": "sale",
    "tran_class": "ecom",
    "cart_id": cart_id,
    "cart_currency": "EUR",
    "cart_amount": amount,
    "cart_description": "Advertising Services",
    "paypage_lang": "en",
    "customer_details": customer_details,
    "shipping_details": customer_details,
    "tokenise": 2,
    "callback": "url",
    "return": "url"
}
```

From above I get token which I save it for future payment request, but when I try to request using this token I get error `{'code': 422, 'message': 'Unable to process your request', 'trace': 'PMNT0102.65DCFAF6.0002C7A0'}`

**Payment request payload with token**

```
payload = {
    "profile_id": PROFILE_ID,
    "tran_type": "sale",
    "tran_class": "recurring",
    "cart_id": cart_id,
    "cart_currency": "EUR",
    "cart_amount": amount,
    "cart_description": "Advertising Services",
    "payment_token": payment_token,
    "tran_ref": tran_ref,
    "callback": "url",
    "return": "url"
}
```

Can anyone please guide what I'm doing wrong here